# Remotely change view types in recyclerView firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have created three view types in my project along with one MAIN recyclerView which will hold all the other views. **IMAGE VIEW, GRID VIEW & HORIZONTAL RECYCLER VIEW**. *I want to call this three views multiple times* from firebase realtime database.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what the problem exactly. You don't know how to get data from firebase, or you don't know how to show multiple views in recyclerview, or something else?
Can you also share your source code.

Comment: Yes I don't know how to show multiple views in recyclerview from Firebase realtime database.